# ¿Como truncar una variable double a 4 decimales en c#?

Tags: c#

¿Como hacer que una variable double solo me muestre 4 dígitos después del decimal?
que no se redondee.

Comment: Necesitas que la variable solo tenga 4 decimales o que al mostrar la variable solo se muestren 4 decimales?

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo haría así, fácil si la precisión decimal no es obligatoria:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   double example = 12.345678;
   var result = example.ToString("#.0000");
   double numRounded = Convert.ToDouble(result); // No es totalmente preciso
```

**Si usted necesita precisión decimal debe usar números variable decimales en lugar de double.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 decimal numToRound = 12.345678m;
 decimal numResult = Math.Truncate(numToRound * 10000m) / 10000m;
 // Valor en numResult 12.3456
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta le entendí perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

La función `Math.Floor(numero)` te permite obtener el valor entero de un número sin redondearlo.

Podrías entonces multiplicar tu número por `10000`, obtener el valor entero con `Math.Floor` y finalmente dividir para `10000` para regresar al valor original pero manteniendo solo las 4 posiciones decimales.

Ejemplo:

```
double numero = 123.456789;
double numeroConFormato = Math.Floor(numero * 10000) / 10000; // -> 123.4567
```